# Using Java Swing SystemLookAndFeel on Windows machines leads to MemoryLeaks in CachedPainter with JTextPanes

Tags: java, windows, swing, memory-leaks, jtextpane

I am struggling with a nasty problem for many days now. In my Java Swing application, I use two `JTextPane`s extended with Syntax Highlighting for XML-Text as described in this example with some little changes:
[XML Syntax Highlighting in JTextPanes](https://boplicity.nl/confluence/display/Java/Xml+syntax+highlighting+in+Swing+JTextPane)

These two `JTextPane`s are placed in two `JScollPane`s in a `JSplitPane` that is placed directly in the `ContentPane` of a `JFrame`.  The first `TextPane` is editable (like a simple XML-Request-Editor), the second `TextPane` displays XML-Responses from my server backend.

Everything works as expected as long as I don't try to put "many lines" in those `XmlTextPane`s. This results in a pretty fast increase of memory used (going from < 100 MB to 1,000 MB after just a few lines inserted to one or both of the `TextPane`s).

The strange thing is that even resetting the `TextPane`s and/or removing them (or disposing the `Frame` that holds the `Component`s) will not change the memory used at all! Forcing a garbage collection won't change anything, too. Something must still be holding references to the allocated stuff....

In order to see what exactly is consuming all that memory I tried to analyze the application with the Eclipse MATS resulting in this:
[image: Eclipse MATS Results]

This clearly shows that the `CachedPainter` is holding a lot of stuff...
Asking Google it seems that I am not the only one having memory issues with the `CachePainter` but I was unable to find a reason - and even more important - and solution for this.

After messing around with this for many many hours now I found out that this problem **does not** occur when I set my application to use

```
UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getCrossPlatformLookAndFeelClassName());
```

instead of

```
UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
```

With the cross platform Look and Feel, I was able to put thousands of lines of XML content in my `TextPane`s without getting over 200 MB memory used.
With the same code but set to platform Look and Feel (Windows 7), I reach over 2k MB memory usage after ~200 lines

I can reproduce this behavior compiling against JDK7 and JDK8 :(.

What is causing this and how can I fix it?

€dit:
Some additional Informations: 
on further research it seems like some LAFs have problems with d3d buffers. This int[] in the MATS screenshot could be some kind of rendering buffer, too pointing in the same possible direction....
My application already sets this in order to prevent some rendering performance issues (frame resizing for example!):

```
System.setProperty("sun.java2d.noddraw", Boolean.TRUE.toString());
```

I could try to add this flag to the startparameters, too:

```
-Dsun.java2d.d3d=false
```

Or do you think that this won't help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't worry. It's not memory leak.

The `ImageCache` is based on `SoftReference`s. From the sources

```
public class ImageCache {
    private int maxCount;
    private final LinkedList<SoftReference<ImageCache.Entry>> entries;
    ....
```

From [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ref/SoftReference.html)

*All soft references to softly-reachable objects are guaranteed to have been cleared before the virtual machine throws an `OutOfMemoryError`.*

So when you have not enough memory, the cache is cleared to free enough memory.

Comment: Mhh then i don't understand why it keeps crashing for me when it reaches a certain memory usage level.
Like i said, this only happens with SystemLookAndFeel, not with CrossPlatformLookAndFeel.

I use the "publish" method of my SwingWorker to fill those TextAreas so i am pretty sure that threadsafety should be no issue.

€dit:
what also seems to help is to slow the process down. When i add some thread.sleeps here and there the memory used is still growing fast but at least it seems that it no longer crashes. Again, only with the SystemLookAndFeel.... 
There must be something i didn't get ...

Comment: I don't know what is wrong but you can profile more and find out what is the problem. In case of memory leak I call gc, fix amount of instances, do action, call gc and compare instances which were created but not removed by gc.

Comment: looks like with a recent jdk 8 the problem has disappeared (or at least is much weaker). will have to further monitor it...